# Downloaded PDF files have 0 bytes. Why?

Tags: pdf, file-download

I have recently begun experiencing this problem.  I go to download my current bill from Verizon and, after it appears in my download folder, it contains 0 bytes.  This came on all of a sudden.  I had a technical chat with Verizon, before I realized that the files were 0 bytes long,  and they weren't much help.  They suggested my Adobe reader needed updating.

I've looked into Windows 10 error logs and security logs, and there doesn't seem to anything there for the relevant time window.

Does anybody have a workaround for this?  Right now,  my only workaround is to go back to paper billing.  Has anybody else experienced the same problem, with Verizon or with some other server?

**Correction:**  Playing around with it some more,  I found out the following.  The PDF file is not 0 bytes when first downloaded.  It's something like 18KB.  It's only after I try to open it with the Adobe reader that the file length gets changed to zero.

**Addition:** I tried doing the same thing on Android with Chrome, and also got an error indicating a corrupt PDF file.  This just about rules out Edge, Windows, or Windows defender as the source of the trouble.  It doesn't rule out my ISP, or Verizon.  I also tried an alternative format, namely an XLS file that Verizon offers,  but Excel reports that that file is also corrupt.

Comment: Thanks.  Acted on this, and revised the question.

Comment: I have a hunch this is really a firewall problem.  I'm investigating further.